# Git submodules are being -dirty?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I just cloned a repository as a submodule into one of my projects. Al is well and working, but all of a sudden i get this message when I do `git status`;

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#       modified:   wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields (untracked content
)
#
```

And if I do `git diff` I get the following:

```
-Subproject commit 486e51db9b6ce49114c897ed1893a208d2289a29
+Subproject commit 486e51db9b6ce49114c897ed1893a208d2289a29-dirty
```

What is worrying is the -dirty change. What does it mean? How do I fix it? I havent made any changes to the repository. But Dreamweaver may have added stupid _notes folders to it. I have tried to delete them but still have same problem. Is this what is causing it to be dirty?

If I try and do a `git add -A` it still says I have untracked content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the -dirty suffix means the submodule has changed. do this:

```
cd wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields
```

then

```
git status
```

and you'll see what changes are causing your submodule to be dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was as I suspected that Dreamweaver created its *_notes* folders. I found out how to disable this via http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-1671

Just as **@Woodrow Douglass** mentions, I needed to check my submodule folder to see what was changed. And the changes was loads of *_notes* folders created.

Comment: you didn't mention anything about dreamweaver, so I think the answer given by @woodrow-douglass is the correct one to the question posed, and this should be really a comment to that answer. :)

Comment: You can tell git to ignore the generated files - this should help.

Comment: @eis I did mention Dreamweaver :) `But Dreamweaver may have added stupid _notes folders to...`

Answer (score 0):

try `git add wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields`